# Complex Analysis textbook Example question!!

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

I'm reading my complex analysis book and came across an example for the 
mapping $w=(1+i)z+2$.  I am confused on where the $1+2i$ in the $z$-plane part of the picture came from.  I also don't understand where the $-1+3i$ came from either.  I do know that $1+i= \sqrt{2}e^{(i\frac{\pi }{4})}$.  Just don't know where to go from there.

[image: example from text]

Comment: Please format your question with the appropriate Latex code

Comment: Also, isn't the $1+2i$ just what you start with? The point of the picture is to show the effect of the mapping $z \mapsto (1+i)z+2$?

Comment: Thank you! yes it seems as though that is what I start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number $1 + 2 i$ was just chosen arbitrarily as an example. In this example, the author has chosen to assume that $z = 1 + 2 i$.

The number $-1 + 3 i$ is the value of the sub-expression $(1 + i) z$ when $z = 1 + 2 i$.

And finally, the number $1 + 3 i$ is the value of the expression $(1 + i) z + 2$ (also called $w$) when $z = 1 + 2 i$.

Comment: Thank you, That makes so much more sense!